# return dictionary of elements instead only one element from argument in python

Tags: python

i have text `corpus`

`text = "natural language processing and machine learning is fun and exciting"`

`corpus = [[word.lower() for word in text.split()]]`

i have function in class, that returns me vector of word:

```
def word_vec(self, word):
    w_index = self.word_index[word]
    v_w = self.w1[w_index]
    return v_w
```

for example with this code:

`word = "machine"
vec = w2v.word_vec(word)
print(word, vec)`

i have this output:

`machine [ 0.76702922 -0.95673743  0.49207258  0.16240808 -0.4538815  -0.74678226
  0.42072706 -0.04147312  0.08947326 -0.24245257]`

how i can get output by all words in my corpus, not only word which i using in argument of `w2v.word_vec(word)`

i need changes inside my function, not just `print` changes

i guess i need to return `dictionary` in my function with format `all words` : `all vectors`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
vecs = {word: w2v.word_vec(word) for word in corpus}
```

Or `... in corpus[0]` if `corpus` is a nested list as you depict it.

Comment: `<ipython-input-19-a5bbef5bd8e8> in <dictcomp>(.0)
      1 word = "machine"
----> 2 vecs = {word: w2v.word_vec(word) for word in corpus}
      3 print(word, vecs)

<ipython-input-8-f14484f77be9> in word_vec(self, word)
    196         # Get vector from word
    197         def word_vec(self, word):
--> 198                 w_index = self.word_index[word]
    199                 v_w = self.w1[w_index]
    200                 return v_w

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`